# Send command to a detached screen, which changes the active window

Tags: linux, shell, gnu-screen

How can I send a command to a detached GNU Screen session, which changes the current active screen? So if I'm leaving the session on 3-rd window, after giving the command and openning again the screen session I could be in the 4-th window.
I tried something like:

```
screen -r -X 'screen next'
```

but it didn't worked. "next" is a screen command which switches to the next window.

What I want to do is this:
I have a ultra cheep home made seed box made out of Raspberry Pi and a USB HDD. Since it has only 256Mb RAM I can not run all the torrents (about 2000) at the same time.

So what do I do. Divide the torrents in 6 folders, run screen with rtotrrent instance in each folder. Every day I'm stopping the rtorrrent in the running folder and starting it in the next one.

I'm trying to make a shell script to do it for me with cron, but I can not solve this. How to change the current screen window with the next one..

And I want to run it in screen, because I want to be able to see what I'm seeding at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct command to switch to the next window

```
screen -r -X 'next'
```

Answer (score 0):

At least on my version of screen¹, sending commands via `-X` to a detached session doesn't work for things that might change the current window (such as `next` or `select 0`). Other commands such as `stuff`, do work. Maybe it's a bug, I don't know. I suspect it's "by design" since the `-Q select ...` flag has the same issue, and I'd expect that to solve this exact problem, if it could.

I have a solution to your stated problem further down, but I think you can solve your *actual* problem like this:

```
screen -S mysession -p 0 -X stuff 'some commands for your torrents'
```

Here, we don't change the active window, but we send commands to a specific window (`0` in this case) using the `-p` option.

Another, more cheeky answer is "use `tmux` — it has better support for scripting" (:

¹ version 4.06.02 (GNU) 23-Oct-17

---

Hopefully that fixes your problem, but I came here because I truly need to change the active window in a screen session with a script.

And, in trying to address your issue, I found a solution to mine, so I'll add that here in case others are interested.

Notice that if you are manually attached via some terminal, then you can send `next` and `select` commands via `-X` just fine in a script. But of course, we don't want to have to manually attach; we want to automate it.

So ... prepare for an abomination (:

We'll use a separate screen session to attach to the screen session we care about, thus putting that session in the 'attached' state where we can send `select` commands to it from the main script. We'll be scripting screen from inside another scripted screen session.

Let's suppose we have an existing session called `foo`, and we want to send the `select 0` command to it. Just running this does not work: `screen -S foo -X select 0`.

Instead, do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# (the only bash-ism here is $'\n', so you could do it with
# plain 'sh' easily, too)

# You could get this from a commandline argument, etc.
target_session=foo

# A unique name for our controller session. You could append a UUID
# if you might have two scripts running, but they would fight with
# each other anyway - probably best to avoid.
controller_session="control_$target_session"

# Create the controller session.
# It starts in detached state, so we can script against it.
screen -d -m -S "$controller_session" -t attacher

# The default window will be used for attaching to $target_session.
# We make a second window for running our "real" commands.
# We could also do this in a separate process or somesuch.
screen -S "$controller_session" -X screen -t runner

# Attach to the target session
# Note: if someone else was attached (eg: if you were watching), it
# will fail. But in that case, our subsequent command still have an
# attached session to work with, so our overall script will work.
screen -S "$controller_session" -p 0 -X stuff "screen -r '$target_session'"$'\n'

# Now that it's attached, we can run commands which change the active
# window.  This is the real meat of this script, where we do the thing
# we care about.
screen -S "$controller_session" -p 1 -X stuff "screen -S '$target_session' -X select 0"$'\n'

# Hack!
# At least on my system, there needs to be some delay between the select
# command being run, and detaching. Otherwise, it does not take effect.
# 0.01 is too small, 0.05 seems to work, so this should be plenty.
sleep 0.1

# Detach from target_session
screen -S "$target_session" -X detach
# Kill the controller, since we're done with it.
screen -S "$controller_session" -X quit
```

It's not pretty, but I know I'll be using it!